# Error to read a nested json from file to python dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Hello I was trying to read a nested dictionary from file. But it was throwing error as follows

error

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 6 column 17 (char 301)
```

input file content

```
{              "MLJobId": "Model",                  
                "training_config" : {
                "AlgorithmSpecification": {
                    "TrainingImage": "683313688378.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-xgboost:1.3-1",
                    "TrainingInputMode": "File"
                }
}
}
```

code that reads above file

```
import json
with open ('param.json','r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

note : The error looks like the code is not processing the nested values . if i give a simple json it will read .

Comment: I count three opening `{` and two closing `}`. Also note that JSON disallows all trailing commas, so the last comma in the document is an error.

Comment: Thanks @Mark . its my copy paste error . I have tried that as well but still that same error

Comment: With your edited file, I can't reproduce the problem. It's loading fine for me.